# Linking Two Excel Worksheets in One Drive / SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, onedrive, excellibrary, vba

I'm trying to Link multiple Excel files and Upload to One Drive. while opening the Consolidated Excel file from One Drive through browser, displays warning as

> **Links Disabled** Links to external workbooks are not supported and have
>   been disabled.

What i need is(*3 files created in One Drive*)

File 1: **Excel File 1**

File 2: **Excel File 2**

File 3: **Consolidated Excel File**(*linked with Excel File 1 and Excel File 2*)

links to be created from **File 3** to **File 1** & **File 2** inside One Drive. Changes from File 1 & File 2 to be immediately Updated to File 3.

Comment: Hi Guys, Response by Microsoft Answers [Click here to view](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeonline-excel_online/linking-two-excel-worksheets-in-one-drive/4ad1777b-12d8-4a51-861a-41a768dc8322?rtAction=1417663904924)

Answer (score 2):

**The following solution does NOT work using a web browser.**

*Note: The CID link provided below is a made up ID. It is just a sample, for visual purposes. Each OneDrive email account has a different and unique CID.*

---

### Get your CID

*If you already know your CID, go to step 4*

1. Go to [onedrive.live.com](http://onedrive.live.com) and log in to your account (where the files are parked)
2. **Open any folder** and copy the link from the address bar. For visual purposes...Ej, https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=1A23456CD7EF8GHI&id=1A23456CD7EF8GHI!107

- *Step 2.1:*

[image: Step 2.1]

- *Step 2.2:*

[image: Step 2.2]

3. Extract your CID from that link (`https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=1A23456CD7EF8GHI&id=1A23456CD7EF8GHI!107`). The CID It's a 16-digit alphanumeric ID. On this example, it would be this: **1a23456cd7ef8ghi**

### Create a local network drive/place

4. Now, we'll use your CID to create/edit a link to **map** OneDrive as a [network location or as a network drive](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows) onto your local computer.

   - [Network Location](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows): `https://d.docs.live.net/1A23456CD7EF8GHI/`
   - [Network Drive (FTP Drive)](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows): `\\d.docs.live.net@SSL\DavWWWRoot\1A23456CD7EF8GHI\`
   - Just in case you're wondering, the **user name** and **password** (credentials) are the **same as your OneDrive account**. Use the **complete** email address as user name
5. Done!

**Please remember that your OneDrive CID will be different than the one I provided on this example since each account has a unique CID. Please update the link on step 4 accordingly**

---

### Making OneDrive cloud service work for us =)

Now that you set up the "environment" you will be able to work with your excel workbook located in OnceDrive, like if they are local files. With a network drive/place mapped on your computer, you can now open your OneDrive files straight from that network drive/place.

You can also use the same link from step 4 into our Excel formulas. If the file names are `File1.xlsx`, `File2.xlsx` and `File3.xlsx`; this is how your formulas would look on `File3.xlsx`:

```
 |-----A-----|-----B------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1| Name      | Address                                                                            |
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2| ='https://d.docs.live.net/1a23456cd7ef8ghi/SomeFolder/[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1 | 456 Somewhere St
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
3| John Doe  | =='https://d.docs.live.net/1a23456cd7ef8ghi/SomeFolder/[File2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: How would I make this work with a corporate OneDrive account? There is no CID in the URL.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file you want to use, in a web browser, and check the url? Each file has a CDI. This CDI is the actual file name & ID across the servers & web @M.Sqrl

Comment: An alternative way to find the CID, which also works for corporate OneDrive is by looking into the OneDrive settings file `global.ini`. For personal OneDrive it is usually located at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Personal\global.ini`, for business it's `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business1\global.ini`. The `Business1` could also be `Business2` to `Business9` because it is possible to log into up to 9 business OneDrive accounts on a single machine. I don't know, however, if this way of mapping OneDrive works for business OneDrive.

Comment: Yet another way of getting the cid's is from the registry. Open RegEdit and navigate to `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Personal` for private OneDrive, or `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1`, (can again be `Business#`, where # is 1 to 9) for business OneDrive.